# Startup splash image

Tags: boot, display, pi-zero

I have a headless pi Zero that has a tiny Nokia 5110 monochrome LCD (AdaFruit). This is a prototype for a consumer device. The raspbian boot sequence takes a while to boot, and I was wondering if it is possible to write to the display early on (before the run level scripts start). Just something to tell the user that the device is starting up. I'm guessing it is not possible but thought I'd ask. The Nokia uses GPIO/SPI.

Comment: The proper way to have it on at bootup is via a hook in `initramfs` a.k.a `initrd`, the initial virtual file system that is used to boot linux. The init script for this lives in `/usr/share/initiramfs-tools/init`. You must rebuild the ramdisk using `update-initramfs -u`. There are a lot of caveats to using the ramdisk so you may be better off putting a `systemd` hook, which runs after root file system and kernel is loaded so a slight delay. For this you need to learn how to write linux "services" (aka daemons) with a special syntax for scripts that run at boot.

Comment: Well, if you really want to get into the device as soon as possible you might consider creating a device driver for it but as it would depend on other modules this would not be a trivial route.  As it is run as part of (privileged) kernel code there will not software permissions issues but it is not something for the faint-hearted I believe - and I am not sure where you go to start down that path...